# Chain, product, quotient rule exercises: ($\ln\frac{(x+1)^2}{x^2+1}$ etc)

Tags: calculus

I'm currently learning the chain, product and quotient rules of differenentiation. Only I'm lacking some exercises. I'm looking for a website, or something that's available online with some more difficult examples of those rules combined. For example things like this:

Find the derivative of:
$$\ln\frac{(x+1)^2}{x^2+1}$$
and stuff like: Find the derivative of:
$\sin(e^x)\tan(x^2)$

I'm just lacking some of these Exercises, does anyone know a website + answers?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[These](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~karstenc/Teaching/M184_Prac2.pdf)(a list of derivatives) look relevant.